# Select2 drop-down list is not repositioned to show added tags

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](https://select2.github.io) (version 4.0.2) to allow users to select multiple values and make tags of them. The problem is that when the span holding the tags is expanded after new tags are selected, the drop-down values list area is not repositioned accordingly.

This figure shows the Select2 area containing several previously selected values, prior to selecting additional values:

[image: Figure 1]

This figure shows what happens after I select one or more choices, which are hidden because the tags area is taller than it was, but the drop-down options list is stuck in the same position:

[image: Figure 2]

If I take focus from (blur) the tag area, the drop-down is re-displayed in the proper position to show all of the currently selected values/tags:

[image: Figure 3]

**Question**

How do I get the drop-down options area to dynamically reposition as new tag values are selected? Can I intercept a Select2 event and somehow force it to recalculate the vertical position? Or perhaps `blur()` then `focus()` the span each time a selection is chosen?

Answer (score 4):

The solution I came up with was to force the drop-down element to be resized whenever a drop-down choice was selected or de-selected, which required catching the `"change"` event:

```
// Apply Select2 to the <select> element
var select2Elem = $("#" + controlID).select2(opts);

// Force drop-down list to resize upon select/unselect
select2Elem.on("change",
    function(evt) {
        select2Elem.resize();
    }
);
```